# Построение регрессии для числовых и категориальных признаков

Tags: машинное-обучение, регрессия

Необходимо оценить Среднее Количество Автомобилей на участке дороги.

Имеются данные о распределении скоростей за некоторый промежуток времени. Зачемечно, что СКА зависит от размера выборки данных скоростей,поэтому регрессия `Y = f(x_1)` могла бы помочь оценить СКА.

Сложность в том, что другие предикторы так же влияют на СКА, будучи как числовыми `(x_2, .., x_k)`, так и категориальными `(c_1 = data provider, c_2 = road class, .., c_m)`.

Мы считаем, что `x_1` влияет на СКА значительно больше, чем другие предикторы. Так же сам предиктор `x_1` можем зависеть от других предикторов.

Поэтому мы намерены получить множество регрессий `Y = f(x_1)` в зависимости от наборов `(x_2, .., x_k, c_1, .., c_m)`.

Количество предикторов `k` и `m` невелико (`<10`).

—

Имеет ли смысл сперва разбивать датасет на кластеры `(x2, .., x_k  y_1, .., y_m)`, а затем находить регрессию `Y=f(x_1)` для каждого кластера?

Или лучше рассматривать все предикторы `(x1, x2, .., x_k, y_1, .., y_m)` вместе и ожидать, что `x1` получит больший вес, чем остальные?

Comment: Обычно в задачах машинного обучения если есть какие-то рабочие методы, то заранее сказать, какие взлетят, а какие нет нельзя. Нужно пробовать на конкретных данных разные методы. В соревнованиях по машинному обучению вообще обычно строят много разных моделей и их результаты смешивают хитрым образом.

Comment: К комментарию уважаемого CrazyElf  добавлю. Имейте ввиду, что поскольку у вас предикторы и числовые и категориальными, то просто регрессией вы скорее всего не обойдетесь. А то, что один предиктор зависит от других -  еще более усложняет задачу, ибо требование взаимонезависимости предикторов - одно из основных в классической многомерной регрессии. Ну и непонятно, в одном месте у вас (x2, .., x_k  y_1, .., y_m) -  это датасет, который вы разбиваете на кластеры, а в другом  -  это "все предикторы".

Comment: И еще.  Среднее по выборке вообще-то не должно (или точнее - должно очень слабо) зависеть от размера выборки. Это основы и статистики и машинного обучения. При таких вводных -  регрессию строить вообще бессмысленно. Что-то не то у вас в логическом осмыслении вашей задачи.

Comment: @passant Я вообще в этих перечислениях названий "предикторов" потерялся, честно говоря, я бы из такого описания не смог бы задачу декомпозировать )  А что касается категорий - ну, можно же `one hot encoding` применить и тогда регрессия теоретически возможна и на категориальных признаках, хотя качество её, конечно, вопрос дискуссионный

Comment: @CrazyElf -  не только вы, но похоже и ТС тоже заблудился. :-). А я даже путь искать не решился, пока задача не будет приведена к более-менее вменяемой постановке.

Comment: @passat, спасибо за комментарий!
Размер выборки, о котором было упомянуто, - по смыслу - количество автомобилей, проехавших в некоторый промежуток времени по заданной дороге. Мы ищем зависимость среднегодового количества автомобилей от этого значения

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за интерес к задаче!
Главная фича - количество автомобилей, проехавших по дороге.
Однако
1) одни поставщики данных фиксируют, например, лишь треть автомобилей, другие -п пятую часть (мы не знаем, какую именно часть, но сравнивая данные разных поставщиков видим это) значения
2) На разных типах дорог и местности искомая зависимость отличается (условно, в деревне хуже работает интернет, и данные того же поставщика  получаются более разреженные). Выходит, что зависимость годового количества автомобилей от главной фичи всё ещё сохраняется, но имеет несколько другой характер.

Comment: @CrazyElf, таким образом мы ищем зависимость от одной фичи, характер которой меняется при разных условиях (тип местности, дороги, возможно, количество полос и даже ограничение скорости на дороге)

Comment: @АртёмОщепков Ага, ну я говорю, это надо пробовать. Я бы попробовал оба варианта - и модель по всем данным, где категориальные признаки закодированы через `one hot encoding` (тогда модель сможет подобрать каждому значению категориального признака свой коэффициент и учтёт особенности, которые вы описали). И отдельные модели по каждой категории тоже можно попробовать строить, если данных не слишком мало. Потом можно посмотреть насколько хорошие получились модели и, возможно, как-то объединить результаты разных моделей вместе.